# Summing within a recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Summing within a recursion: Does it always produce a StackOverflow Error?

```
public final static float getAlpha(int t, int i, int N, float[] P, float[][] B, float[][] A, int[] O)
{
    float alpha;
    if (t==1)
    {
        alpha = P[i] * B[i][O[0] - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        float sum = 0;
        int k;
        for (k=0; k < N; k++){
            sum = sum + (getAlpha(t-1, k, N, P, B, A, O) * A[k][i]);
        }
        alpha = sum * B[i][O[0] - 1];
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

I get that error for the line:

```
sum = sum + (getAlpha(t-1, k, N, P, B, A, O) * A[k][i]);
```

Is there any creative solution?

Comment: `StackOverflow` will always happen if your recursion is **infinite**.

Comment: How big is N?  Happens with small N?

Comment: Is it possible that T starts as a non-positive number?  i.e, if t = 0 this will not terminate.

Comment: Thanks, those are good ideas. I will keep checking!

Comment: What is i set to in the first call?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a dynamic programming approach. This way values are never calculated a second time, and you don't need to worry about a stack overflow.

Create a t by N array.

so `Array[i][0] = P[i] * B[i][O[0] - 1]`

From here you sum all of the elements of the previous row and multiply by `A[k][i] and B[i][O[0] - 1]` where `k` is the index of the row of the previous column and `i` is the index of the row of the current column.

For the final result you need to use the value of `i` that you originally called it with.

This way you only are doing `2*t` multiplications and `t*N*N` summations. significantly less than what you are doing now.

If you need help with the actual implementation you should look up the veterbi algorithm. It is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your t is very large (or there is a mistake and it is less than 1).

So, unless you can rewrite this function to have tail recursion (difficult, given that the recursion happens in a loop), and you are running on the correct type of JVM that does tail recursion (only a few actually do), a recursive solution is always going to overflow the stack.

At this point, I would suggest trying to rewrite it in an iterative fashion. This probably means starting from the bottom up, and storing intermediate values in an array.

Comment: Just to clarify, my "very large" I think you are talking 100,000 or so, right?  I've never done that much recursive work for large Ns, but I think that most JVMs should have plenty of memory for a few thousand recursions.  NOTE: I don't think that N matters much, cause you will recur on t first.

Comment: I was more thinking 10,000 or so, but I don't honestly know for sure. It probably depends on not only the JVM, but also the size of the stackframes.

Comment: Sorry the current code wouldn't work. i is varied every time it is called recursivily. You need an `txN` array.

Comment: Yea, I just realized that, and it is slightly more in depth than I want to get into without a java IDE.

Comment: Yeah I just explained how to do it in a dynamic programming way, but I really don't feel like coding in Java at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me ike you're unnecessarily recalculating the same values over and over again. Your recursion is following a tree pattern where every branch is the same, and every sub branch of those branches are the same, etc. So the amount of calculation involved is exponentially larger than it should be.

Comment: While that may be true, it wouldn't be the cause of a stackoverflow. It would just be the cause of poor performance.

Comment: Fair point. But if the initial `t` is large enough to cause a stack overflow, this program probably won't finish running before the heat death of the universe.